# Specifying a jar file to run with JDK not JRE?

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, runtime

I have created an application that uses runtime compilation via the JavaCompiler class, this application runs fine in NetBeans however if I run the Jar file it throws a nullpointer at this line;

```
final CompilationTask task = javaCompiler.getTask(null, null, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
```

From what I understand it's due to NetBeans launching my application with JDK, whereas when launching the application from the Jar file it uses JRE which doesn't have access to a compiler using; `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`

Is there any setting or file I can edit in NetBeans that will add some constraint to the manifest? Or is there a simple way of ensuring whoever uses the app will be able to run it using JDK without having to manually specify their paths?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea.  You can't depend on every user having a JDK installed.  What are you compiling at runtime?

Comment: It's an application I had to make for my final year project at university, I'd be assuming that the user would always have JDK since there is no actual consumer. The application takes a users inputted code in a text area and compiles a class with the code inside at runtime. The only other option I see is to create a class that locates the users JDK, then use Runtime().exec to execute the main class using this.

Comment: Google found this - 3rd hit: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and

Comment: I don't think that DZone tutorial is actually a solution in this case, it depends on `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`, which returns null if running from JRE. @Zee Best if you know the user has Java 8 you can include `tools.jar` as an application resource and load the compiler from there using reflection. With Java 9+ I think you'll have to just warn the user if they're running with JRE instead of JDK.